# php password_hash and password_verify issue

Tags: php, html, password-hash

I try to understand how form, and password_hash and verify work. Here is the simple code that I wrote.
 The result that I get is "invalid Password"

What am I missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="pwd"> 
Password: 
 <table> 
   <tr> 
     <td><input name="passwd" type="text"/></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
     <td align="center"><br/> 
      <input type="submit" name="submit_pwd" value="hash"/> 
     </td> 
   </tr> 
 </table>   
</form> 

<?php
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];

echo "Password :   <BR>".$passwd."\n <BR>" ; 
echo "Hash     :   <BR>".$hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT).  "\n <BR>";

if (password_verify($passwd, $hash)) {
echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
} 

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your version of Php? (`echo PHP_VERSION;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain what is going (and not going) on here.

What the following does...

```
$hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT). "\n <BR>"
```

is an assignment, where you're trying hash a password, which will also contain a line break, a space and a `<BR>` tag.

Then, trying to verify if the entered password matches the entered password, and a line break, and a space and `<BR>`.

- That would be pretty hard to do, wouldn't you agree?

You should also be getting an undefined index notice about `$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];`, so wrap that whole code in a conditional statement using the named submit input.

You will need to change your code to the following, while removing `. "\n <BR>"` entirely.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_pwd'])){

    $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];

    echo "Password :   <BR>".$passwd."\n <BR>" ; 
    echo "Hash     :   <BR>".$hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify($passwd, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
   } 
}
```

---

Here's a simple test using MD5 as an example in order to prove this, (note I didn't use `password_hash()` here, since that produces a different hash and would be hard to actually prove the difference); code partially borrowed from http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Keep in mind that MD5 produces the same hash value.

```
$str_good = 'apple';
$str_bad = 'apple'.  "\n <BR>";

echo md5($str_good); // produces 1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f
echo "<br>";
echo md5($str_bad); // produces cb2a3d3161fcc99dcf5e4ccd3bfbb14c
echo "<br>";

if (md5($str_good) === '1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f') {
    echo "Would you like a green or red apple?";
}
```

You will notice that the assignment without the added `.  "\n <BR>"` produces a different value than the other.

- This is the same thing that is happening to your code here.

> *"What am I missing?"*

- The question isn't about what is missing, but about what is too much.

The fix is as simple as just removing `.  "\n <BR>"` which is "what is too much".

Comment: Thank you. It about how php interpret this line

echo  <BR>".$hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT).  "\n <BR>";

I will keep in mind

Comment: @Dragonet You're welcome. If you wish to mark the question as solved, tick the checkmark till it turns green next to the answer. This tells everyone that a solution to the question was found.

Comment: done

I just learnt that php interpret this line 'code' <BR>".$hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT). "\n <BR>"; 'code' as 'code' $hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT). "\n <BR> 'code' not 'code' $hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) 'code'

Answer (score 0):

The `$hash` variable won't set properly when inside an `echo`.  Use this:

```
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
$hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo "Password :   <BR>".$passwd."\n <BR>" ; 
echo "Hash     :   <BR>".$hash.  "\n <BR>";

if (password_verify($passwd, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Comment: That isn't my downvote here, but you probably got it because of your not being sure about it and/or the "try this". Although your answer does fix the problem here (I know why), it would be good for the OP and everyone else, if you were to explain the answer, that way there won't be any guesswork, or people asking you what you did to fix their code.

Comment: Thank you @GentlemanMax.

I just learnt that php interpret this line

'code' <BR>".$hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT).  "\n <BR>"; 'code'

as
'code'  $hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT).  "\n <BR> 'code'

not 
'code'  $hash = password_hash($passwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) 'code'